# Read two files and write data in sequence in third file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files. The first file has constant details (like reference file). Another file has dynamic data in it. It has values associated with first file keys using a shell script.

File1.txt

```
CIN|Template|Date
```

File2.txt

```
1234|QWERTY|2019-03-18
5678|ASDF|2019-03-18
9012|ZXCVB|
```

I want output file `Output.txt` like:

```
{CIN: 1234
Template: QWERTY
Date:  2019-03-18}
{CIN: 5678
Template: ASDF
Date: 2019-03-18}
{CIN: 9012
Template: ZXCV
Date: }
```

Comment: Did you try anything (not my downvote, btw)?

Comment: ...which is to say -- a good question is not just a specification for code you want someone else to write, but is actually a *question* about an isolated problem you encountered *while writing code yourself*, showing your existing effort and where/how you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F\| '             # set field separator
NR==FNR {                # process first file
    split($0,a)          # split on field separator and hash to a
    next
}
{                        # second file
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)   # iterate all fields and output refering titles from a
        printf "%s%s: %s%s\n",(i==1?"{":""),a[i],$i,(i==NF?"}":"")
}' file2 file2
```

Output:

```
{CIN: 1234
Template: QWERTY
Date: 2019-03-18}
{CIN: 5678
Template: ASDF
Date: 2019-03-18}
{CIN: 9012
Template: ZXCVB
Date: }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=File1.txt
FILE2=File2.txt

IFS="|"
read -a Header < $FILE1
ColumnsCount=${#Header[@]}

while read line; do
    read -a Values <<< $line
    echo -n "{"
    for ((i=0; i < $ColumnsCount; i++)); do
        echo -n "${Header[$i]}: ${Values[$i]}"
        if [[ $i -lt $((ColumnsCount - 1)) ]]; then
            echo
        fi
    done
    echo "}"
done < $FILE2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR {first= $1; second=$2; third=$3;} NR > 1{print "{" first ":" $1 "\n" second ":" $2 "\n" third ": "$3  "}" }' File1.txt File2.txt


{CIN:1234
Template:QWERTY
Date: 2019-03-18}
{CIN:5678
Template:ASDF
Date: 2019-03-18}
{CIN:9012
Template:ZXCVB
Date: }
```